# Jenkins build on Windows Server 2012 failing due to node-gyp, works from command line

Tags: node.js, windows, jenkins, node-gyp

I'm setting up a Jenkins build on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.  Part of the build involves using npm to install from package.json:

package.json

```
{
    "name": "localtest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": url_for_git_repo
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "karma": "^0.13.9",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
        "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.3.1",
        "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "webpack": "^1.12.0"
    }
}
```

When I run `npm install` from command line it works successfully but it fails when the Jenkins build attempts it.  The full Jenkins output can be viewed on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pyEy16Je). The specific error seems to be `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.node-gyp\0.12.7\Release\node.lib' [C:\bld\localtest\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]`.  The folder `Release` doesn't actually exist on my system so that would seem to be a sensible error message other than the fact that the install completes successfully from command line (both cmd.exe and git bash FWIW).

With this working from command line I think the problem is related to some environment variable or other, or maybe something with the path but having tried to replicate the path from the command line into the Jenkins build I still haven't had any joy.  Does anyone have any suggestions for what I might try next?

UPDATE 1:

I've just set the Jenkins service to log on under my account rather than the system account and restarted it. The build completed successfully. I think that makes it even more likely that this is a problem in the environment variables somewhere.

UPDATE 2:

I installed the [Environment Injector](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin for Jenkins so that I could update the environment variables which were different between my user and the system user. This still resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer, but it's what worked out for me.

I ended up doing

```
npm uninstall -g node-gyp
```

And then uninstalling nodejs.  I then re-installed nodejs and ran

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

And the Jenkins build is now running successfully